# Random forbidden 403 error with Spring WebServices Client

Tags: web-services, spring

We have a webservice client implemented with Spring WS.
This is a snippet of the code:

```
<bean id="aClient" class="class.aClient">
    <property name="messageFactory">
        <bean  class="org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="messageSenders">
        <list>
            <ref bean="httpSender" />
        </list>
```

The client call works fine for a random period of time: minutes, hours, even days, and suddenly the next error appears:

**org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Forbidden [403]**

There is a basic user/password authentication and the client runs inside Weblogic.
I've tried changing the minimum thread pool number, setting preemptive authentication, 
and the result is the same. Randomly the error appears.
When this happens, the server implementing the WS is working fine (tested with soapUI)
The call always works again when the application server restarts.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.
I can provide more code if needed.

Thank you

David

Comment: @David - Can you do this - try to break up the web-service using SOAPUI - If its transactional web-service - then u need extra effort :) .. but if its read only then can fire many requests and try to break that .. Also do you get any Server Side exception when this happens ? ( I am pretty sure you are not getting any )

Comment: I can try to break up the web service, but always this error happens, I test the server with soapUI and it's working fine. Also I can get the server log but I think like you there aren't exceptions.